# Eclipse shows annotated errors but builds successfully

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, raspberry-pi, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 13.04 to develop for the raspberry pi.  I configured a cross-compiling toolchain following this guide: http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/

I got my hello world program to **compile and run correctly** on the raspberry pi, but Eclipse annotates all STL includes as errors.

What I've tried:

- Rebuilding the project
- Rebuilding the index (Index->Rebuild)

I'm guessing I'm missing some path in my configuration, but I'm not sure which one.  I did do a considerable amount of research on google and I couldn't find any specific solution to this problem.

So the question is, how do I configure Eclipse to see the C++ STL include paths being used by my build command? (arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

**Update:**
I was looking through the include paths I had blindly copy-pasted before, and noticed that one of them was supposed to point to the C++ STL, but didn't go deep enough in the folder structure.  I fixed it by changing `.../include` to `.../include/c++/4.7.2` and that fixed the STL not being seen by eclipse.

But now I have a new problem: when I include a file, for example, `#include <string>`, I can't use the string type; it underlines every instance of `string` and says `Type 'string' could not be resolved.`  **But if I restart Eclipse the errors go away**... until I make any changes to the code, which brings the red lines back.  And still, **the program compiles successfully.**

Answer (score 0):

CDT can be very capricious sometimes. But **if your paths where wrong, the program wouldn't run properly, so your compiler knows about STL**. I went into this kind of issue while importing some third-party libraries (source files), and switching the order of the includes fixed it. In your case it might be more complicated...

If you can't get rid of this errors, you still could disable some specific errors and turn it into simple warnings but this would be a bit error prone and dangerous:

`Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Code Analysis > Use project settings > Switch the errors that are bugging you into warnings`

Good luck with that.

Comment: The compiler knows about STL, yes.  But Eclipse isn't the compiler, it's an IDE, which has a different system for detecting available include files.  In my case, there's a disconnect between the compiler and the IDE.  And disabling errors isn't really an option, seeing has how if the IDE can't see the include files, then almost every line I write is underlined in red.

Comment: Yes, course. I know the difference between the IDE and the compiler I use every day. This is not my point, and I know that my answer is not of a big help. The point here was just to warn you that CDT is still a bit buggy and, for example, I noticed that the windows version shows more problems than the linux one regarding the type of issues you are talking about. And, believe that I'm sorry not to be able to help more here.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that my problem was fixed by simply changing the include path to the C++ STL to something else and then back again.

Steps:

1. Find the include path to the STL and change it from `.../include` to `.../include/c++/4.7.2`
2. Restart eclipse, you might notice it's partially working now (there was still some strange behavior going on that I mentioned in the question)
3. Change `.../include/c++/4.7.2` back to `.../include`
4. Restart Eclipse and now it should be working.